# Ensure that variables are forgotten after constructor in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, oop, variables, memory

In my current understanding of javascript's object model, all variables defined in a constructor become members of the object you use the constructor to create. For instance:

```
function A() {
    this.memberA = 0; //memberA is now a property of A;
    var memberB  = 1; //memberB is now a private member of A, it can only be accessed by functions defined in the constructor

    this.getMemberB = function() {
        return memberB;
    }
}

var a = new A(); //object of A now exists
```

however, this exposes a problem, at least in my understanding. Say I wanted to some operations in the constructor and store them temporarily.

```
function A() {
    this.memberA = 0; //memberA is now a property of A;
    var memberB  = 1; //memberB is now a private member of A, it can only be accessed by functions defined in the constructor

    this.getMemberB = function() {
        return memberB;
    }

    var calculation = /* some complex operation that I don't want to put on a single line, like I'm doing now for simplicity*/

    this.memberC = calculation;
}
```

From my understanding wouldn't `var calculation` become a member of class A, and although private, it would stick around as long as an instance of A exists, hogging memory.

My question is, how can I ensure that the variable declared in the constructor be forgotten at the conclusion of its execution, and thus freeing up memory, provided that my understanding is correct.

Comment: `calculation` will always be in the scope of `this.getMemberB`, so, all you can do is assign a value like `null` to it, and minimize its memory footprint. If you are only assigning a primitive value to it anyway, don't worry about it.

Comment: but 'calculation' isn't in the scope of this.getMemberB? I think you miss read my code

Comment: I think that wouldn't be any problem because if `calculation` is primitive it doesn’t use that much memory to be worried about and if it's a big object, when you assign that to `this.memberC` it's reference, so still is takes same amount of memory. If you really concerned about that little amount of memory that `calculation` might take, just do calculation in a function and return the result.

Comment: `calculation` is in the same scope as the function that is assigned to `this.getMemberB`, hence the function as access to it. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there is small typo in your first code block:

```
var a = A(); //it is incorrect, you should use
var a = new A();
```

About `var` in your constructor this variables are local for scope of constructor and will be destroyed if you do not use it in some closures (it is function that uses variables from outer scope).

For example in you first code there is local variable `memberB` that in normal case should be destroyed, but `getMemberB` functions uses it inside function body so it can not be destroyed until `getMemberB` is alive.

So all local variables created in constructor will be destroyed and free memory if nobody use them.

Comment: So basicly, if a 'var' is not used in another function defined in the same scope, it will get destroyed.

Comment: *"and will be destroyed if you do not use it in some closures"* if they are, then it's an implementation detail of the JS engine. Since JS has `eval`, an engine cannot reliably determine whether a variable is actually accessed in a closure or not (at least if `eval` is used).